# Basic auth + suexec to authenticate as linux user

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, basic-authentication, suexec

Is it possible to configure Apache 2.4 with `mpm-prefork` to let users authenticate as a Linux user (using e.g. basic auth), and then `setuid` the process to this user before executing the request?

It seems like `mod_suexec` allows for switching users, but from what I understand these users are hardcoded in the apache2 config. I can't find an example where `suexec` is used to `setuid` to a particular authenticated linux user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mod_auth_external to authenticate apache users against the system password database.

https://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/

Comment: Could you include an example of a config using `mod_auth_external` to `setuid` to the authenticated user?